Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Auth'
Am trying to do phone auth in firebase nextjs but getting typescript error as Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Auth'.
the following is the firebase config file where i get data from from env.local
// firebaseConfig.ts
import { initializeApp, FirebaseApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, Auth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getAnalytics, Analytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore, Firestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app: FirebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics: Analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const auth: Auth = getAuth(app);
const db: Firestore = getFirestore(app);

export { app, analytics, auth, db };


the following is the code where am getting a phone auth recaptcha error
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber, Auth } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "@/app/lib/firebaseConfig"; // Ensure this path is correct
import CountrySelect from "./CountrySelect";
import PhoneNumberField from "./phoneNumber";
import { Country } from "@/app/types/types";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    confirmationResult: any;
  }
}

export interface PhoneWithCountryProps {
  setSelectedCountry: (country: Country | null) => void;
  selectedCountry: Country | null;
  setOtpState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  savedPhone: string;
  setSavedPhone: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
}

const validatePhoneNumber = (country: Country, number: string): boolean => {
  const countryCode = country.phone;

  switch (countryCode) {
    case "91":
      const indiaRegex = /^[6-9]\d{9}$/;
      return indiaRegex.test(number) && number !== "9876543210";

    case "971":
      const uaeRegex = /^5\d{8}$/;
      return uaeRegex.test(number);

    case "94":
      const sriLankaRegex = /^7\d{8}$/;
      return sriLankaRegex.test(number);

    case "968":
      const omanRegex = /^7\d{7}$/;
      return omanRegex.test(number);

    case "966":
      const saudiArabiaRegex = /^5\d{8}$/;
      return saudiArabiaRegex.test(number);

    default:
      return false;
  }
};

const PhoneWithCountry: React.FC<PhoneWithCountryProps> = ({
  setSelectedCountry,
  selectedCountry,
  setOtpState,
  savedPhone,
  setSavedPhone,
}) => {
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleForwardButtonClick = () => {
    if (
      !error &&
      selectedCountry &&
      validatePhoneNumber(selectedCountry, phone)
    ) {
      const appVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
        "recaptcha-container", -- this line is giving error --
        {
          size: "invisible",
        },
        auth
      );

      const phoneNumber = `+${selectedCountry.phone}${phone}`;

      signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then((confirmationResult) => {
          setSavedPhone(phone);
          setOtpState(true);
          // Store confirmationResult to verify the OTP later
          window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setError("Failed to send OTP. Please try again.");
          console.error("Error during signInWithPhoneNumber:", error);
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex">
        <CountrySelect
          setSelectedCountry={setSelectedCountry}
          selectedCountry={selectedCountry}
        />
        <PhoneNumberField
          initialPhone={savedPhone}
          setPhone={setPhone}
          error={error}
          setError={setError}
          selectedCountry={selectedCountry}
          setOtpState={setOtpState}
          validatePhoneNumber={validatePhoneNumber}
          handleForwardButtonClick={handleForwardButtonClick}
        />
      </div>
      <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PhoneWithCountry;


The error happens here:
      const appVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
        "recaptcha-container", -- this line is giving error --
        {
          size: "invisible",
        },
        auth
      );


Which line of code causes the error?  Please edit the question to show what you've done to debug this so far.

@DougStevenson const appVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
"recaptcha-container", -- this line is giving error --
{
size: "invisible",
},
auth
); this line gives the error

@DougStevenson but when i put the auth argument in the first place there is no error window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
auth,
"recaptcha-container",
{
size: "invisible",
},
); but am not receiving otp to the mobile

Instead of leaving your debugging information in comments, you should edit the question to show all relevant information. There is an edit link at the bottom of your post.  People are likely to miss small details in large blocks of code unless you point it out clearly.

@haribabu You have to pass the parameters in the correct order

You're not using the RecaptchaVerifier API correctly.  See the API documentation for the RecaptchaVerifier constructor:
constructor(
    authExtern: Auth,
    containerOrId: HTMLElement | string,
    parameters?: RecaptchaParameters
);

You can see that the Auth parameter comes first.  You're passing the parameters out of order.  It should be like this instead:
const appVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
    auth,
    "recaptcha-container",
    { size: "invisible" },
);

